# Django: Template Tag unable to load image.Only reading media image

Tags: django, image, django-templates, pisa

I am trying to generate a PDF with django pisa module.

### views.py

```
def reportPdf(template_src, context_dict):

        template = get_template(template_src)
        context = Context(context_dict)
        htmlRender = template.render(context)
        resultObj = StringIO.StringIO()
        pdfObject = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(htmlRender.encode(
            'utf-8')), resultObj,link_callback=fetch_resources)
        response = HttpResponse(resultObj.getvalue(), content_type = 'application/pdf')
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'inline;filename=sample.PDF'
        return response
 def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
         import project.settings
         path = os.path.join(project.settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(
                                            project.settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
         return path

class abc():
     def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
     // some code
     return reportPdf('pdf.djhtml',{'pagesize': 'A4',"refer_data":detail}
```

### settings.py:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media"))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

### Template:

pdf.djhtml:
code for image available in media folder:

```
<img src="/media/sample.jpg"/>
```

Above works fine as i have incorporated media in views.py

But below code doesn't load the image.

`refer_data.image.url = http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg` (Consider this http url as sample for testing).This Image url I am getting from a API call.

```
 {% if refer_data.image.url != "" %}
        <img src="{{refer_data.image.url}}"/>
 {% else %}
       <img src="noimage.png"/>

 {% endif %}
```

Could someone analyse and share some idea where I am missing?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should pass the absolute url of the image

Comment: @trinchet...I didn't get you.Could you please how to pass absolute url of image?Realy helpful

Comment: When you do `{{refer_data.image.url}}` you get something like `/images/w3schools_green.jpg` instead of the full path `http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg` so, you should prefix with domain name etc..

Comment: When I do {{refer_data.image.url}} then i get full path http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg. This creates a confusion like how to pass absolute url..Could you please elaborate more

Comment: @trinchet..Though it loads the full path of the url but image is not loaded.When I comment out  fetch_resources method in views.py then it loads the images.

Comment: I want to load both at single point of time.Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure why you need this method `fetch_resources`, but can't you just get the url of the image directly from the model?

Comment: To use logo in pdf I want fetch_resources method and many more images needed to be loaded in pdf while generating pdf.Along with this also I want to load image with URL as http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg..I am not dealing with model to get image url.What I am getting is from API call.And API give me Image URL as http://......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if you are dealing with a local or absolute HTTP URL in `fetch_resources`, an example using the [validator](http://validators.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package:

```
import project.settings
import validators

def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    if validators.url(uri):
      return uri
    else:
      path = os.path.join(project.settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(
                                            project.settings.MEDIA_URL, ""))
      return path
```

For an absolute url (`http://www.google.com`) return the url else for a relative url `/media/myimage.jpg` it returns the joined media path.

Comment: Hay Marcs.Your answer is perfect.Since I have to use URLValidator function from validators module...Can I get this work out?